# Modify django's username policy?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

Django default admin authentication module disallows use of the `\` char in usernames. How can I make it accept it?

It looks like it's possible to edit `contrib/auth/models.py`'s username field's validator, but that won't do because it requires a change to django's base code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom [regex validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/validators/#regexvalidator) and a custom [user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) in order to achieve this. Be sure to set `USERNAME_FIELD` and `REQUIRED_FIELDS` in your model definition and `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.

*custom_userprofile_app.models.py*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True,
                                help_text=_('Required. 30 characters or fewer.'),
                                validators=[
                                    validators.RegexValidator(r'^(.*)$',
                                                              _('Enter a valid username. '
                                                                'This value may contain any characters', 'invalid'),
                                    validators.MinLengthValidator(5, 'Username must be at least 5 characters'),
                                ],
                                error_messages={
                                    'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
                                })
    # The rest of your fields, etc
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','first_name','last_name']
```

*settings.py*

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_userprofile_app.User'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override django's default User model and then edit the regex validator.
You are just required to create a child class of base user model and then define a setting for that.

Read how to specify custom user model @ [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)