# How to limit Django's builtin auth allowed username characters?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-users

I'm using the **builtin auth app of Django** not the *django-allauth*. Is it possible to limit the allowed special characters in Django's **builtin** auth app usernames? the default allowed characters are:

Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_

I want to be:

Letters, digits and ./_

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably create a custom `User` class that inherits from the default one, but has a custom validator.
Like the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35544161/4585157

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own authentication backend. That way you can make the rules you want.

Comment: Thank you, is there any tutorial about that?

Comment: Check django docs here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/